# My Postgres replication isn't functioning, see below for specific error

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, postgresql-9.2

I have two Postgres databases set up in a Primary/Secondary configuration. I tried to setup replication between them, but have hit a road block. Where am I going wrong?

I have checked various configuration files: `recovery.conf`, `postgresql.conf`, `pg_hba.conf`, and all seem to be set up correctly.

This is the error I have found in the `pg_log` folder:

```
cp: cannot stat ‘/var/lib/pgsql/walfiles/00000002000001CA0000003E’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/var/lib/pgsql/walfiles/00000003.history’: No such file or directory
2019-04-16 16:17:19 AEST  FATAL:  database system identifier differs between the primary and standby
2019-04-16 16:17:19 AEST  DETAIL:  The primary's identifier is 6647133350114885049, the standby's identifier is 6456613398298492847.
```

I am using PostgreSQL 9.2.23.

This is my `recovery.conf`:

```
standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'host=10.201.108.25 port=5432 user=repl-master password=111222333'
restore_command = 'cp -p /var/lib/pgsql/walfiles/%f %p'
trigger_file = '/var/lib/pgsql/i_am_master.pg.trigger'
recovery_target_timeline = 'latest'
archive_cleanup_command = 'pg_archivecleanup /var/lib/pgsql/walfiles %r'
```

I'd expect replication from Primary to Secondary. So far, nothing.

Appreciate any input/ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't set up replication correctly. You cannot use `pg_dump` to create the replica, you have to use a physical backup technique like `pg_basebackup`.

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/warm-standby.html#STANDBY-SERVER-SETUP) for details.

Do not use PostgreSQL 9.2, it is out of support.